# Filter list items by length in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list like `["a","ab","abc", "abcd"]`

How to get a list that only has the items which have a length > 2.

Means the result is `["abc","abcd"].`

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Why would Xie delete his question?  It's a valid one, if rather simple.  Others might come across this question and gain some insight as they begin their first steps into Haskell

Comment: @bheklilr The question lacks the most basic expertise, which violates the ["Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and was answered by your rather ironic first comment.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Then vote to close it, don't suggest deleting it.  [Questions that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality, may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).  While this question is not the best formed, it is not extremely off topic or of very low quality, in my opinion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Natalie's answer is perfectly correct, but as an alternate form you could also write it as

```
filter ((> 2) . length) ["a", "ab", "abc", "abcd"]
```

Or with list comprehension as

```
[str | str <- ["a", "ab", "abc", "abcd"], length str > 2]
```

All three are equivalent

Answer (score 10):

```
filter (\x -> length x > 2) ["a","ab","abc", "abcd"]
```

Comment: Go with bheklilr's cleaner answer.

Comment: I personally do not find bheklilr's answer cleaner. Nor dirtier. Just different.

Comment: @DanielWagner I think all three answers are about equally "clean" and valid.  My point was not to provide a better answer, just some different ways of doing the same thing in Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

The input is of the form `[[a]]`, which has no guarantees about length not being infinite. So relying on `length` even finishing is overly optimistic in general, and inefficient if it does. Better to express the condition as a pattern match instead:

```
[ xs | xs@(_:_:_:_) <- ["a","ab","abc","abcd"] ]
```

Writing this expression as a `filter` is left as an exercise for the reader.