# Filter file by length BEFORE saving haskell

Tags: file, haskell, filter

A similar question has been asked, but with a list in hand:
[Filter list items by length in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410293)

I already know how to get a word list from a file

```
getWords path = do contents <- readFile path
                   return (lines contents)
```

And then I can filter it to get words of specific length, but...

What I am wondering is if there is a way (preferably not in point-free style - unless necessary) to filter the file by length **before** saving it as a list of words.

For example, words.txt is file of words with 1 word per line.

```
filteredWords <- filter (\x -> length x == 3) *Read words.txt in place*
```

Comment: FWIW, `(lines contents)` is a list of lines, not words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the fact that `IO` is also an instance of `Functor`

```
filteredWords <- fmap (filter (\x -> length x == 3)) $ getWords path
```

Since you asked about how to do it without using `getWords`: you can use the function composition operator `.`.

```
filteredWords <- fmap (filter (\x -> length x == 3) . lines) $ readFile path
```

I think `readFile` is in `Prelude`, if it's not then it will be in `System.IO`

Comment: This one is short and sweet and worked perfectly with the getWords I already have. I'll wait for a few more answers if any can be done without using getWords (still one liner), if not, I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure I completely understand this question. It centers around the notion of "before saving it as a list of words", which seems to be misleading in a lazy language. In Haskell, doing

```
let list1 = someLongList
    list2 = filter p list1 
in use list2              -- (but do not use list1)
```

will not cause `list1` to be stored in memory completely: rather, elements not satisfying `p` will be discarded immediately.
Hence, the notion of filtering a list before "saving" it is not meaningful: this is a standard optimization that the compiler will do for you.

Rather, separating input/output and filtering is the preferred way. The alternative, namely mixing I/O and pure computation in the code is generally regarded as a worse approach. Haskell types also encourage the first, simpler, approach.

Comment: Before "filteredWords <-" happens, I want to first read the file, and then filter it with given length so when "<-" happens, filteredWords will have only words of that specific length.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Here is an example using `pipes` that avoids materializing the full list of words.  Only the words of the specified length will be retained in memory:

```
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as Pipes
import qualified System.IO as IO

filteredWords :: FilePath -> IO [String]
filteredWords path =
    IO.withFile path IO.ReadMode (\handle -> Pipes.toListM (
        Pipes.fromHandle handle >-> Pipes.filter (\x -> length x == 3) ))
```

So, for example, if your file had 1,000,000 words, but only 4 of them had length 3, then this program would only generate a list of length 4.  All the other elements would be discarded immediately after they were read and not stored in memory in some intermediate list.